# Boolean check is not working Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to perform boolean check

```
num = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
```

in the session section, using feed_dict num is set from 0 to 10

```
if(num != 0):
   ...perform action...
```

The above boolean check outputs always true even through num is 0.

Comment: check the `type` of num.

Comment: `num` is a [placeholder](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops/placeholders).  It doesn't have a value -- The value needs to be fed to it during execution...

Comment: @mgilson the value has been fed using feed_dict

Comment: @Bhansa can I know how do i make the type check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TensorFlow program is composed of two parts: the construction phase and the execution phase:

- In the construction phase, you build a computation graph. No computation is actually executed in that phase. When you create the placeholder, you are just creating a node in the (default) graph.
- Then in the execution phase (using a `tf.Session()`), you run the graph (typically multiple times). The placeholder `num` itself is just a node in the graph, so it will always be "True". However, if you want to run the graph to compute its value, then you must call `num.eval()` (or equivalently `session.run(num)`). When evaluating a node, if it depends (directly or not) on a placeholder, then you *must* specify that placeholder's value using a `feed_dict`.

So here is the proper program:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> num = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
>>> with tf.Session():
...   for val in range(11):
...     if num.eval(feed_dict={num: val}):
...       print(val, "is True")
...     else:
...       print(val, "is False")
... 
0 is False
1 is True
2 is True
3 is True
4 is True
5 is True
6 is True
7 is True
8 is True
9 is True
10 is True
```

As you can see, everything works as expected, in particular 0 is False and the rest is True.

**Edit**

If you want to have a condition in the graph itself, you can use `tf.cond()`, for example:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> num = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
>>> a = tf.constant(3)
>>> b = tf.constant(5)
>>> calc = tf.cond(num > 0, lambda: a+b, lambda: a*b)
>>> with tf.Session():
...   print(calc.eval(feed_dict={num: +10}))
...   print(calc.eval(feed_dict={num: -10}))
8
15
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If this is the case, is there any way to perform boolean check in the function in order to run certain part of the code only when the boolean is true? @miniquack

Comment: Sure, you should use `tf.cond(condition, A, B)`: it creates a node in the graph that will evaluate the `condition`, and if `True` it evaluates `A` and returns the result, or else it evaluates `B` and returns the result.

Comment: @Vimlan.G I edited my answer to add an example of `tf.cond()`.